# Help identify part

Tags: pcb, components, identification

Anyone know what this is, I need the particular part name. The photo is of an audio amplifier:

[image: image of the part in question]

Comment: KBPC 810

http://www.micropik.com/PDF/KBPC804.pdf

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a full-wave bridge rectifier.

Edit: After rotating and squinting it looks like it's part number might be KBPC-something? If you Google that plus rectifier I'm sure you can track down the datasheet.

Comment: KBPC 810

http://www.micropik.com/PDF/KBPC804.pdf